# How to automate password entry?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, automation

I want to install a software library (SWIG) on a list of computers (Jenkins nodes). I'm using the following script to automate this somewhat:

```
NODES="10.8.255.70 10.8.255.85 10.8.255.88 10.8.255.86 10.8.255.65 10.8.255.64 10.8.255.97 10.8.255.69"
for node in $NODES; do 
  scp InstallSWIG.sh root@$node:/root/InstallSWIG.sh
  ssh root@$node sh InstallSWIG.sh
done
```

This way it's automated, except for the password request that occur for both the scp and ssh commands.

Is there a way to enter the passwords programmatically?

Security is not an issue. I’m looking for solutions that don’t involve SSH keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SSH the right way to do it is to use keys instead.

```
# ssh-keygen
```

and then copy the *~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub* file to the remote machine (root@$node) into the remote user's .ssh/authorized_keys file.

Comment: "Security is not an issue. I’m looking for solutions that don’t involve SSH keys."

Comment: This does not answer the question. What if I am unable to obtain an SSH key?

Comment: If you look at the edit history, the original version didn't have that stipulation: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5514405/revisions

Answer (score 7):

Here’s an `expect` example that `ssh`s in to [Stripe’s Capture The Flag server](https://stripe.com/blog/capture-the-flag) and enters the password automatically.

```
expect <<< 'spawn ssh level01@ctf.stri.pe; expect "password:"; send "e9gx26YEb2\r";'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the task using [empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net/), a small utility from sourceforge. It's similar to expect but probably more convenient in this case. Once you have installed it, your first `scp` will be accomplished by following two commands:

```
./empty -f scp InstallSWIG.sh root@$node:/root/InstallSWIG.sh
echo YOUR_SECRET_PASSWORD | ./empty -s -c
```

The first one starts your command in the background, tricking it into thinking it's running in interactive mode on a terminal. The other one sends it data from stdin. Of course, putting your password anywhere on command line is risky due to shell history being preserved, users being able to see it in `ps` results etc. Not secure either, but a bit better thing would be to store the password in a file and redirect the second command's input from that file instead of using echo and a pipe.

After copying to the server, you can run the script in a similar manner:

```
./empty -f ssh root@$node sh InstallSWIG.sh
echo YOUR_SECRET_PASSWORD | ./empty -s -c
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look into setting up passwordless ssh keys for that. [Establishing Batch Mode Connections between OpenSSH and SSH2](http://www.atmos.albany.edu/facstaff/rmctc/ssh2/) is a starting point, you'll find lots of information on this topic on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Wes' answer is the correct one but if you're keen on something dirty and slow, you can use [expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) to automate this.