# Linux expect command analog

Tags: linux, shell, expect

While developing a shell script to copy logs from lots of remote servers, I found out a problem that I need to pass a password for each ssh connection to each server (and it makes me very nervous:) ). I know that it is better to use keys, but the process of adding them will take a lot of time due to our admins. As an option I found that it is possible to use the `expect` command, but it is not installed on our servers, and installation will take also a lot of time.

So, is it possible to simulate `expect` command behavior via plain shell scripts to pass passwords to ssh non-interactively?

Comment: public keys, cron+rsync, central logging server, there are a lot of solutions to this problem... your real problem is your admin.

Comment: `expect` only has to be installed on the machines that will be doing the SSH-ing. If, for security or whatever reasons, you can't install that software, do your servers have python installed? Python has two packages you could use - `pexpect` (python expect) or `fabric`, which can do automation tasks. The security concern can be mitigated if you use [`ssh-agent`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) with keys and passwords in the SSH keychain. But copying files can be done with other tools like David mentioned.

Comment: You should speak to your management about how the admins are forcing you to use a horribly insecure system to do business intensive tasks and then get them to expedite the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a compiler, you should be able to compile `expect` from source. If `expect` is difficult to compile, try [empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net/), it's a very small and simple program - if anything compiles, it should, too. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514405/how-to-automate-password-entry/9439027#9439027) is an example of using it to automate ssh login.

Do note that others are right: ssh keys are your friends, while both `expect` and `empty` are usually just ugly and unsafe workarounds.